# how to print application name provided in .yml file in every log statement?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I wanna print my application name provided in `.yml` file in my `log4j` logs

my `log4j` pattern is

```
LOG_PATTERN=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] boot%X{context} - ${PID} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN} [%t] --- %c{1}: %m%n
```

Currently I am getting logs like

```
2017-09-16 15:53:35.687 INFO 18302 --- [  restartedMain] mc.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : My Log print statement
```

The format i want my logs to print

```
2017-09-16 15:53:35.687 INFO 18302 --- [**APPLICATION_NAME**] [  restartedMain] mc.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : My Log print statement
```

How can I put the application name in there in `log4j` log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a web application, you can use a Filter and [MDC](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html).

See example:

```
public class MDCFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            MDC.put("appName", "**APPLICATION_NAME**");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove("appName");
        }
    }
}
```

The Filter above will put your app name into MDC and then you can use a log pattern to print the app name.

Based on your log pattern, see modification below:

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} boot%X{context} - ${PID} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN} [%t] --- [%X{appName}%n] %c{1}: %m%n
```

Note: `%X{appName}%n` which will output what was placed in the filter `MDC.put("appName", "**APPLICATION_NAME**");`

The above will output the following:

```
2017-09-16 15:53:35.687 INFO 18302 --- [**APPLICATION_NAME**] [  restartedMain] mc.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : My Log print statement
```